# Trying to understand delegates

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have a class named 'MyWearablesViewController' in which I have writen a protocol as

```
 protocol MyWearablesViewControllerDelegate {
    func myWearablesViewControllerDidFinishedChangingTracker(viewController: UIViewController)
}
```

I have created a global variables as

```
var delegate: MyWearablesViewControllerDelegate?
```

and I have used this method several times in 'MyWearablesViewController' like

```
self.delegate?.myWearablesViewControllerDidFinishedChangingTracker(self)
```

Now I want this to trigger a method in my other class named 'HomeViewController' the class is declared as

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,MyWearablesViewControllerDelegate
```

in my ViewWillAppear I have written this code

```
let myViewControllrer = MyWearablesViewController()
myViewControllrer.delegate =  self
```

and implemented its function as

```
func myWearablesViewControllerDidFinishedChangingTracker(viewController: UIViewController) {
    // some code
}
```

But my delegate is not being called. Please guide me what am I missing ?

Edit:  'HomeViewController' is in a TabBarController which contains another ViewController named 'MoreViewController' which is basically a tableView. 'MyWearablesViewController' is pushed when user tap on a cell in 'MoreViewController'

Comment: Did you present the `MyWearablesViewController`? If it is never presented, how can the delegate method ever be called?

Comment: @NDoc that was a Typo sorry for that.

Comment: @Sweeper I do push it, and it is viewed to user but the delegate did not get called.

Comment: Can you show me how did you push the view controller?

Comment: This code is excuted in didSelectRowAtIndexPath in 'MoreViewController'    let myViewController = MyWearablesViewController()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)

Comment: Okay I now understand why your code isn't working. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, good news and bad news...

The good news is that you that your understanding of the delegate is absolutely correct! But the bad news is that you misunderstood a more basic concept.

You said that in `viewDidAppear`, you have this code:

```
let myViewControllrer = MyWearablesViewController()
myViewControllrer.delegate = self
```

You created a new instance of `MyWearablesViewController`, and you assigned `self` to the `delegate` variable. So far so good.

However, in `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` method, you did this:

```
let myViewController = MyWearablesViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
```

You created *another* instance of `MyWearablesViewController`! And *this* instance is not the instance you created in the `viewDidAppear` method! As a result, this new instance is independent of the other instance you created earlier. And its `delegate` property actually is `nil`.

So, how can you fix it?

According to your comment on NDoc's answer, you want the delegate to be set to the `HomeViewController` instance.

To access the `HomeViewController` instance, you must first get the tab bar controller, and use the `viewControllers` property.

```
// in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method
let tabBarController = self.parentViewController!.parentViewController! as! UITabBarController
let homeVC = (tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! HomeViewController
```

Note that I assume your `HomeViewController` is embedded in a navigation controller. If not, use this instead:

```
let homeVC = tabBarController.viewControllers![0] as! HomeViewController
```

And finally, you can set the delegate:

```
// in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method
let myViewController = MyWearablesViewController()
myViewController.delegate = homeVC
navigationController?.pushViewController(myViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for Explainnig in detail. But one more question please, why we need to self. delegate=self right before pushing viewController ? why not in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: @Byte Actually, you _can_ do it in `viewDidLoad`. But you need to understand that whenever you write `MyWearablesViewController()`, you are creating a _new_ instance of that class. So you need to somehow reference an instance created in `HomeViewController` from `MoreViewController`. As long as you set the delegate and present the _same_ instance of `MyWearablesViewController`, it will work. But the code in your question creates and presents a different instance of `MyWearablesViewController` from the one you created in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

on your MoreViewController's prepare for segue, just before you push MyWearablesViewController. You can do this

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "pushSegue" {
            let vc: MyWearablesViewControllerDelegate = segue.destinationViewController as! MyWearablesViewControllerDelegate
            vc.delegate = self
        }
}
```

Comment: I am not using Segues and storyBoard.

Comment: So how do you implement your "push" without segue?

Comment: I am using Xib and creating NavigationController programatically